# How to push objects to arrays and send as FormData?

Tags: jquery, arrays, form-data

I'm appending data from a list of `<li>`'s to a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) object with:

```
media_links_array = [];
$('.media_links_ul:first li').each(function () {
    var media_type = $(this).attr("data-media_type");
    var media_link = $(this).text();
    var myObject = {
        "media_type": media_type,
        "media_link": media_link
    }
    media_links_array.push(myObject);
});
myFormData.append("media_links", media_links_array);
```

**Expected Behaviour**

I expected it to send (in Firebug Net > POST) as:

```
--------------- nnnnnnnnn Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_links" 

{"media_type":media_type,"media_link":media_link}
```

**Current Behaviour**

But it is sending as:

```
--------------- nnnnnnnnn Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_links" 

[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: Because that is what happens when toString() is applied.

Comment: FormData.append expects a string file or blob to be it's second parameter. You gave it an array which is none of those things... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: And why would you need a formData object for this, it's just two strings you're trying to send to the server, surely there are easier ways to do that, as in jQuery.ajax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(media_links_array)` will give you your JSON object as a string.

Comment: note: this doesn't work with some browsers (http://caniuse.com/json), A-grade browsers are fine, but if you need to support something like IE7 or lower, then you'll need a polyfill (http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/)

Comment: @Populus Right, but that's also a concern for FormData. If we can assume FormData exists, we can also assume JSON.stringify does.

Comment: Thanks very much, and for additional info.

Comment: And just for follow up, on server side in Python to get it back to an array:   `media_links = request.forms.media_links  media_links = ast.literal_eval(media_links)` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python